# My web service operation call only opens test page in IIS - I am not sure how to call the operation to return my xml

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, web, soap

I am new to web services.

I have built a web service in C# that consumes a third party service and then returns the XML response from that call in a web method.

When I test this in IIS on the local web server it works perfectly.

However when I try to call or invoke the service via the URL I use on the test page I can't return a response.

If I use a GET I simply get the test page loading and the message I can't use this test page outside of the local server.

In short, I simply want to know how to call the web method externally and mimic the INVOKE button being pressed so I get the response passed back.

This is probably really simple but I can't get my head around it.

[image]

In addition if I use Postman to try and call the URL:

WebService.asmx?op=GetSalesOrders

I get the error message detailed below which is a step forward but I am still unsure about how to package up a call to this service

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the service by making a POST request with a properly formated SOAP message to this URL:

```
<path>/WebService.asmx
```

You get the WSDL of the web service by making a GET request to this URL:

```
<path>/WebService.asmx?wsdl
```

You can use that WSDL to build a client or test the service with something like SoapUI. See [this](https://d-petre-bogdan.medium.com/the-wsdl-is-not-the-soap-web-service-97f307c4a90b) and [this](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls/) for more details.

That invocation page or URLs with parameters like this:

```
<path>/WebService.asmx?op=GetSalesOrders
```

are just provided for convenience to allow you to poke at the service and make sure the service is running. They should not be used in "real" calls.